# Wygwam 3 and tables

Tags: wygwam

I just upgraded to Wygwam 3 and I noticed whenever I cut and paste table tags within the source code field the tables get stripped out and replaced with `<p>` tags. Inserting other code within the source option works fine.

Has anyone noticed this?

Answer (score 2):

As of Wygwam 3.1 you can turn off the "Restrict allowed HTML?" setting.

This was a feature to prevent people from adding unwanted HTML to their content fields.